# CS0234 error with System.Linq namespace in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, vs-web-site-project

At my company, we have tiered environment for our web applications (development, staging, production).  I made a bunch of changes to one of my applications and deployed them to the development environment (Windows 2003 w/ IIS 6.0).  I also had to make an immediate change to one of the user control files that needs to fix issue with the current production application.

I just deployed the one file to the staging environment (Windows 2003 w/ IIS 6.0), which is an exact copy of production on got the following ASP.NET 2.0 compilation error.

> Exception type: HttpCompileException 
>   Exception message:
>   d:\inetpub\myapp\BaseControl.cs(3):
>   error CS0234: The type or namespace
>   name 'Linq' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System' (are you missing an
>   assembly reference?)

I copied the original file from production (Windows 2003 w/ IIS 6.0) back down to staging and got the same error.  I also recycled and restarted the application pool.  I still get the same result.

Has everyone experienced this issue and know how to resolve it?

**UPDATE:**

The .NET 3.5 framework is installed on the development and staging server.  Each environment is hosted on the same server.  The development environment is working just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My web.config file was missing from my staging environment.  I copied the web.config from the production environment and everything is working...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have System.Core available, as this is where System.Linq lives. Do you have .NET 3.5 installed on the environment?

Answer (score 0):

you need .net 3.5 to use System.Linq or anything related to linq