# Import statement in .ascx causes compile error exception on production server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Why would this line in an .ascx file:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Linq" %>
```

cause an Compile error exception on our production server:

> CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

It works fine on our development and test environments. We use LINQ extensively throughout the site, although it is the only place where we include it in an .ascx file with an Import-statement. The site is a .NET 3.5 web application.

Comment: Please ensure your production server has the correct version of .net framework installed and IIS is registered accordingly - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046075/cs0234-error-with-system-linq-namespace-in-asp-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the .Net Framework Version being used by the Application Pool on your server.
It should be 3.5 or above.

Refer this for [how to set application pools](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/applicationPoolDefaults)

- Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager:

  - If you are using Windows Server 2008 or Windows Server 2008 R2:
    On the taskbar, click Start, point to Administrative Tools, and then click Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
  - If you are using Windows Vista or Windows 7:
    On the taskbar, click Start, and then click Control Panel.
  - Double-click Administrative Tools, and then double-click Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
- In the Connections pane, expand the server name, and then click Application Pools.
- You can set the framework version here